# Admin rights on non-server Windows installations

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, administrator

I have gotten into an argument with a friend on another discussion forum about operating system user rights. My question is, is it a best practice to use a non-admin account for everyday use on a regular Windows installation? He seems to think this is only important for domain admins.

http://news.povray.org/povray.windows/thread/%3C594d5dc7%241%40news.povray.org%3E/?mtop=416703&moff=12

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very much a matter of opinion and depends on how much security you desire and what kind of threats you expect to face. However, there is a prominent option you didn't mention and could possibly be unaware of. So I will cover that.

With modern Windows versions (Vista and newer) UAC automatically keeps you in an unprivileged state most of the time. However, the newest versions of Windows (8 & 10+) have begun to allow many elevation requests (those requested by Windows binaries) to succeed silently. I personally prefer that this not is the case, but YMMV.

If you would like to make all elevation requests require approval, and assuming you have an edition of Windows that includes the Local Security Policy Manager, you can use the Local Security Policy Manager to disallow silent privilege escalation and/or even require your password for elevation. Click the start menu and type `secpol` to search for the presence of the Local Security Policy Manager. Right click the `Local Security Policy` icon and choose `Run as administrator` (just to ensure it has the needed privileges).

From there navigate to `Local Policies > Security Options` and find the item near the bottom named `User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode`. I suggest using `Prompt for Credentials` which will require a password every time elevation is requested by an application and is similar gksudo behavior on Ubuntu Linux and the like. `Prompt for Consent` is also available if you want to simply click yes or no on UAC prompts. You may also choose the secure desktop options if you are worried about attempts to remote control your computer for malicious purposes.

I will say that in my experience as a computer repair tech dealing with both home users and businesses the improved security resulting from UAC, when properly implemented and used, has completely changed how I personally approach security advice for my clients. Before I accepted that it was mostly a lost cause for the majority of users and that I could explain many best practices to them but ultimately even if they followed every single one only disconnecting from the internet and not using it would keep them from needing to call me every year or so to clean up the mess their computers had become.

UAC has completely changed that. Now when my clients call me I find myself sitting down to (mostly) well-behaved computers with limited crap-ware (mal-ware riddle games and free apps and the like). Compared to before, each service call started with a few minutes of just getting the most glaring malware under control. Obviously, YMMV, but my experience with UAC is that its privilege de-escalation makes using an explicitly unprivileged account redundant (when paired with a little common sense).

It's also worth noting that unprivileged accounts on the versions of Windows prior to UAC were almost unusable due to even legitimate third-party software always assuming it would have privileged access to everything. This too is something that has changed due to UAC making it necessary for third party software vendors to get their software to follow standard security best practices outlined by Microsoft.

Comment: I'll keep those tips in mind if I upgrade to Windows 10.

Comment: They are applicable to Windows 7 as well. Apologies if I did not make that clear. Windows Vista/7 defaults to `Prompt for consent` where Windows 8/10+ defaults to `Prompt for consent for non-Windows binaries`. Other than that everything I said is the same for Vista, 7, 8, and 10.

Answer (score 1):

From a security perspective, it makes sense to use separate accounts for day-to-day work. This is the only way to be (reasonably) sure, that no applications run with admin rights, without your explicit authorization. That said, it's a balance between convenience and security.

Running day-to-day as admin can be very tempting, especially when dealing with certain software packages that don't seem to like to cooperate with "Run as Administrator" in their updates like Virtual Box... Sometimes it is kind of a pain, but can save MANY headaches to have users with no admin rights at all. I personally recommend to give standard privileges to everyday user whether it's server or non-server OS.

In the end it comes down to if you're OK with having to explicitly authenticate when performing admin tasks or not.